# JQuery firing to early

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a website for my school, where you search for books through php, and when you click on a book it brings up a form to fill in a students info. However, when the JQuery runs when the document loads, the object I am trying to target is not in the page yet, this is because the page loads the object when the user types in the search bar. How do I delay the function until I have loaded the required objects?

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<section>
    <img id="reading" src="img/reading.png" alt="person reading" />
    <p>Any Book you want, at your Fingertips.</p>
    <p class="subtext">Use the searchbar below to search for any book </br> in the Summerhill Library by name, author or ISBN.</p>
    <input type"search" class='search' name='search'  placeholder="Please enter Name, Author, ISBN or Catagory Number." onkeyup='searchq();'/>
</section>

<div class='results'>
    <h2>Results</h2>
      <div id='output'>

</div>
</div>



<div class='removeform'>
    <h1>Book Lending</h1>
    <!-- name -->
    <p class='tagfullwidth'>Student Name</p>
    <input class='fullwidthinput' type='text' />
    <!-- bookname -->
    <p class='tagfullwidth'>Book Name</p>
    <input class='fullwidthinput book'  type='text' />
    <!-- yeardata -->
    <div class='columns'>
        <div class='column'>
            <p class='tagfullwidth'>Year</p>
            <input class='halfwidthinput' type='text' />
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
            <p class='tagfullwidth textsecond'>Class</p>
            <input class='halfwidthinput second' type='text' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- date -->
    <div class='columns'>
        <div class='column'>
            <p class='tagfullwidth'>Today's Date</p>
            <input class='halfwidthinput grey' type='date' />
        </div>
        <div class='column'>
            <p class='tagfullwidth textsecond'>Expected Return Date</p>
            <input class='halfwidthinput second grey' type='date' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- teachername -->
    <p class='tagfullwidth'>Teacher Signature</p>
    <input class='fullwidthinput' type='text' />
    <!-- submit -->
    <button class='scroll'>Submit Book Lend</button>
    <p class='closebtn'>close</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.removeform{
    background-color:#fff;
    width:1300px;
    height:720px;
    border-radius:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:100px;
    position:fixed;
    left: calc(50% - 650px);
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
        $('.post').click(function(){
            $('.removeform').css('visibility','visible');
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: .post is a div created by the PHP, sorry for not saying that earlier...

Comment: This isn't very clear? Where's that script tag in the document? How are those elements loaded when the user types ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is javascript properly linked to html? Why is the script not running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730796/is-javascript-properly-linked-to-html-why-is-the-script-not-running)

Comment: Appologies, the JQuery is within the HTML, I seperated  to make it easier to read, but it ended up creating confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to target the dynamic `.post` nodes:

```
$('#output').on('click', '.post', function() {
   $('.removeform').css('visibility','visible');
});
```

`$('.post').click(...)` targets the *current set* of `.post` nodes, it is not a "live" list. Using event delegation, you can attach the event listener to a common (static) parent and only act on event targets that match the supplied selector (`.post`). Since the event fires on the parent, there is no problem acting on dynamically added nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use $(document).ready() https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.post').click(function(){
        $('.removeform').css('visibility','visible');
    });
});
</script>
```